# Execute SQL from external file without opening it in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a huge .sql file (1.5 gb). I generated it from scripting a datasbase in Sql server 2008. Now i want to run the script on another machine to create the same database with all the data, but when i try to open it, SSMS throws an out of memory exception. The machine has 8gb of ddr3 ram, so the computer can handle it. How can i run my file, copy.sql, which has the t-sql code to create my database without opening it? Something like this in a query window in SSMS:

```
   exec copy.sql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried osql.exe or sqlcmd.exe? They probably will handle it better.

Also, you could export the data as bcp which would make it easier to import since it's so large.

Comment: No I havent. How do you use them?

Comment: Like this for win authentication `osql -E -i copy.sql` Use -U and -P for SQL logins Run from a command prompt. For data BCP is probably a better choice, it will be much faster

Comment: I tried the backup option first, but it would run and never create my file. No errors or anything. I'm running osql now. It appears to be working. I'll check for the creation of my database when its done. Thanks

Comment: It ran but i dont see my database. I looked in SSMS and saw nothing. Where did it put it or how can i tell where it created it?

Comment: USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [CompleteClosing]    Script Date: 05/18/2012 09:20:18 ******/
CREATE DATABASE [CompleteClosing] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'ccDev60', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL$DEVDB\data\ccDev60.mdf' , SIZE = 554304KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 80KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'ccDev60_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL$DEVDB\data\ccDev60_log.LDF' , SIZE = 3164032KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO

Comment: I got it. I changed my paths in the file i generated to match a path on the other pc where the script would be ran